# All Drivers Gone from Computer(No USB or Wireless Driver) Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virus

Last night, I was trying to restore my iPhone, got it stuck in recovery mode, and in the process had to install known software(iReb, iRecovery, etc). The problem is, now my computer is seriously messed up. It does not identify any USB device and I get a "no Wireless adapter/hardware found", so I cannot access the internet. Luckily, I have a dual-boot ubuntu set up. I think that all the drivers are gone, but I cannot be sure. All i know for sure is that wireless (which was working perfectly before) says hardware is no available and USB ports don't seem to work for any device. I can still use, for example, Eclipse IDE and other things that don't require internet. If this was a virus, I saw no other manifestations of a bug in my computer. This has hindered my work.

Comment: If you have an answer to it, post it and mark as "correct". Or if a user posted an answer that fixed it, mark theirs as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by doing a system restore to four days ago. This got the USB and Wi-Fi working.

Answer (score 1):

First, backup all of your data from Windows 7 onto either another partition, or an external source (hard drive, flash drive, whatever)

Second, try a repair install of Windows (instructions can be found [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html) or [here.](http://windows7.iyogi.com/installation/windows-7-repair-installation/))

Answer (score 1):

I'd try [sfc /scannow](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310747) to try to restore the default drivers (and any other mucked up system files) - this SHOULD leave USB usable again, then reinstall the drivers for anything that needs additional drivers.

Comment: I'm sorry, but are these programs or command line prompts(i'm a newbie)

Comment: ok, got it. i will try this and let you know

Comment: command line prompt - editing answer with a link

Comment: It says all files are fine  no errors found.

Comment: that means the basic drivers, including USB.sys are there. check in device manager to see if there's any ! s or of devices are disabled.